# lam having a challenge in making a drop down list that has sub options when mouse hovers over the parent option

Tags: javascript, html, css

here are my parent options  and the code that l have tried to build 
l would love to add sub options such as phones,radios,speakers to the electronic parent option and many more

```
 <select id="category" name="category"  class="dropDown">


 <option>Categories</option>
 <option>All categories</option>
 <option>Automotive vehicles</option>
 <option>Property</option>
 <option>Jobs</option>
 <option>Job Seekers</option>
 <option>Services</option>
 <option>Home&Garden</option>
 <option>Electronics</option>
 <option>Baby&Kids</option>
 <option>Boats&Watercraft</option>
 <option>Business</option>
 <option>Fashion</option>
 <option>Farming</option>
 <option>Pets</option>
 <option>Sports&Leisure</option>
 <option>Charity Donations</option>
 <option>Community</option>
 <option>Events</option>
 <option>Software</option>
 <option>Food</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: If you don't need the parents to be selectable, you can turn the parents into `<optgroup>` and then make the children the `<option>` tags. However, you can't nest optgroups so you can only have it one level deep. If you need multiple levels, or the parents to be selectable as well as the children, you'd need a custom tree control.

Comment: A title is not meant to contain an entire story. Pls change your title. Take a look here if you need help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

As dman2306 said, you need the `<optgroup>` like this:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <optgroup label="groupA">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
    <optgroup>
    <optgroup label="groupB">
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
    <optgroup>
</select>
```